# Get Sum of Data from BindingSource with Filter

Tags: c#, linq, bindingsource

I have a BindingSource with date filter.

```
bsExpense.Filter = string.Format("[DATE OF CHECK ISSUED] >= #{0:M/dd/yyyy}# AND [DATE OF CHECK ISSUED] <= #{1:M/dd/yyyy}#", dtpExpenseStart.Value, dtpExpenseEnd.Value);
```

I want to get a Total Expense of between the two dates filtered.

```
decimal _dTotal =  ((IList<decimal>)bsExpense.List).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>("Amount"));
```

This one doesn't work.
Does anyone have better idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
decimal _dTotal =  dgvExpense.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["AMOUNT"].Value)).ToString();
```